# Vuong test for non-nested models

Tags: t-test

I performed the following Vuong test for panel data with fixed effects as suggested by Prof. Wooldridge (reasoned from Section 13.11.2 in 2010 MIT Press book, Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data) in the following URL.

https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1332690-performing-vuong-s-1989-likelihood-ratio-test-for-equivalence-of-explanatory-power-in-nonnested-models

I used the same sample and the same dependent variable for the following non-nested two competing models.

xtreg Y x1 x2 x3 x4, fe
predict uh1, e
gen uh1sq = uh1^2
xtreg Y z1 z2 z3 z4, fe
predict uh2, e
gen uh2sq = uh2^2
gen diff = uh1sq - uh2sq
reg diff, cluster(id)

Then I got t-stats (-1.09), which is negative.

### (Std. Err. adjusted for 50 clusters in id)

```
         |               Robust
    diff |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
```

-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------

### _cons |  -.0000913   .0000835    -1.09   0.280    -.0002591    .0000765

How can I interpret the results? How it dffers from the t-stat that is positive?

Comment: I could not get any idea from "xtreg Y x1 x2 x3 x4, fe predict uh1, e gen uh1sq = uh1^2 xtreg Y z1 z2 z3 z4, fe predict uh2, e gen uh2sq = uh2^2 gen diff = uh1sq - uh2sq reg diff, cluster(id)"